# Can't connect to pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I can't connect to pymssql I keep geteing the error 18456. The problem might be that I don't know the right sintax for the connection.

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='GABRIEL-PC', 
                       user='GABRIEL@GABRIEL-PC', 
                       password='', 
                       database='mydb')
```

The server I found by using `SQLCMD -L`, but how can I get the user? Should this be working?

When I use MySQL and wrapserver I don't get this kind of problem, and it works fine
`conn = (server='mysql://root:@localhost/mydb')`

Comment: I don't think you need the `@GABRIEL-PC` in the username. Try leaving it only `GABRIEL`.

Comment: Usually, if you use a full DB url, the username will be part of the URL as in user:pass@server - but for your example, you are passing specific parameters so you don't need to combine them.

Comment: BTW your mysql connection uses the root user - this is **very strongly discouraged** - you should create dedicated users with the appropriate permissions instead of giving someone (or your app) root access.

Comment: I used the full URL `'mssql+pymssql://GABRIEL:@GABRIEL-PC:1433'`, and now I don't get the error anymore, it creates the engine but the only thing that it does it crashes my kernel!
I will look into create a dedicated user  thanks for the tip